# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Script"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I try make Sctipt section by @section Script but @section not worded

```
@section Script {
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/visitManagement.js"></script>
}
```

in layout file:

```
    RenderSection("scripts",required:false);
```

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Script".
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Script".

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Script".]
```

I rename section and rerun project but not fixed

Comment: `scripts` != `Script`.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing @

```
 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

And in my View Page

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="~/js/MyScript.js"></script>}
```